# page posted back due to javascript validation issue

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net, telerik

I am working on asp.net and i have designed a simple form

In that i am making javascript validations.

when any textbox is empty it should display error in label

but unfortunately my page is getting post back each time even though there is error

hence label is getting refreshed and showing no error message

and also blank data is posted to server

Since, using Telerik Controls, button on which i am calling:

```
<telerik:RadButton ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClientClicked="validate" 
                    OnClientClicking="validate" onclick="btnSave_Click">
```

**my javascript code:**

```
    function validate() {

        var flag = 0;
        var errorText = "";
        if (document.getElementById('txtPartyCode').innerHTML == "") {
            errorText = errorText + "\n Please Enter PartyCode";
            flag = 1;
        }

        if (document.getElementById('txtEmailId').innerHTML == "") {
            errorText = errorText + "\n Please Enter EmailID";
            flag = 1;
        }


        if (document.getElementById('txtPhoneNumber').innerHTML == "") {
            errorText = errorText + "\n Please Enter Phone Number";
            flag = 1;
        }



        if (document.getElementById('txtBrockrage').innerHTML == "") {
            errorText = errorText + "\n Please Enter Brockrage";
            flag = 1;
        }


        if (document.getElementById('txtTax').innerHTML == "") {
            errorText = errorText + "\n Please Enter Tax";
            flag = 1;
        }

        document.getElementById('lblErrors').innerHTML = errorText;

        if (flag == 1) //{

            //alert(errorText); 
           //return true;
        //}
        //else
            return true;

    }

</script>
```

Is there any mistake in javascript function???

Comment: Why don't you use require field validator for this

Comment: my TL is not allowing me to do that

Comment: did you try return false; if (flag==1)?

Comment: can you you share the code for calling it

Comment: @Arshad I am calling this javascript function from telerik button

Comment: @Nil Yes i tried it, but still the error/ bug is present

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<telerik:RadButton runat="server" ID="btnTest" OnClientClicking="validate" />
```

javascript will be

```
function validate(sender, args)
{

    // your code 


    if (flag == 1)
    {
        args.set_cancel(true);
    }
    else
    {
        args.set_cancel(false);
    }
}
```

> set_cancel(shouldCancel) - sets a bool value that indicates whether
>   the event will be canceled. Setting true means the event will be
>   canceled.

Comment: Yes, page is not posted back, but upon filling all data, and making flag as 1 , serverside code is not getting executed now. what can be issue?

Comment: You are saying "upon filling all data, and making flag as 1". what does it mean, if flag=1 server side code will not execute.

Comment: Thats good! Please don't forget to mark the correct answer. It may help others. Happy coding !!

Comment: @MicrosoftPS when we returns value as true, it executes server side code , which i am doing on flag=1

Answer (score 2):

For server controls you may want to use <%= lblErrors.ClientID%> and hence it should look like

```
document.getElementById('<%= lblErrors.ClientID%>')
```

I'm not sure how you're calling this function but you should return false if validation fails. i.e

```
if (flag == 1)
  return false;
```

if you're calling it in server button's onclientclick then it should look like

```
OnClientClick="return validate();"
```

I hope it helps!

**Edit:**

In that case you may want to call it as shown below (note: I've not tested it)

```
<telerik:RadButton ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClientClicked="OnClientClicked" onclick="btnSave_Click">

<script type="text/javascript">
    function OnClientClicked(button, args)
    {
        if (validate())
        {
            button.set_autoPostBack(true);
        }
        else
        {
            button.set_autoPostBack(false);
        }
    }
</script>
```

You may want to check Telerik button events [here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/button/examples/clientsideevents/defaultcs.aspx)

Comment: since, the button is telerik, return is not allowing..please see my edited question

Answer (score 1):

Check [here](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/button-onclientclicking.html) for more details, you can try by changing your last `if` block as follows :

```
 function validate(sender, args)
 {
   // your code for validation 
  if (flag == 1)
    {
    args.set_cancel(false);
    }
    else
    {
        args.set_cancel(true);
    }
  }
```

Update your code like :

```
<telerik:RadButton ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" 
OnClientClicked="validate"
onclick="btnSave_Click">
```

Comment: try with  `OnClientClicking="return validate();"`

Comment: problem is that i am using telerik button which is not allowing me return functionname() in function call

Comment: @Damith in telerik controls, "return validate();" is not allowing, only validate(); is allowing

Comment: function does not gets called by OnClientClicked="return validate();"... if it is OnClientClicked="validate();"